# Emulate led flashlight in android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Is there a way to emulate led flashlight in android emulator? I've already tried to see what options are available when setting up the AVD but there was only an emulator for camera!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The emulator can't do that. You need a device. It's also good to develop on a device since the emulator can sometimes behave differently.

If you just want to test different states of the led, then you can create a small view and change the color of that. You need a device if you want to see the led actually working.

Comment: Thanks! I'm testing the new camera2 API because it has been changed for API 23. So I'm getting "bad argument passed" error when using setTorchMode(id, true), but in real device, I don't get that error. But I wanted to make sure that it works on other devices as well without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need an actual device with flashlight to test your flashlight. There is no way to test flashlight in emulator until emulator provides you with led service like in 'geneymotion' you can use your laptops camera as your emulator's camera.